# How to get the title or text from the toolbar for Android

Tags: java, android, xml, android-toolbar

I need some help with my java code for Android app. I want to know how to find out what is the toolbar title when the title shows Inbox, Sent, Draft...etc?

I have tried this:

```
Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
toolbar_text = toolbar.getTitle().toString();

if (toolbar_text == "Inbox") {
   //do something
}
```

It will not fetch the toolbar title as the toolbar_text will show null. I want to know how I can fetch the text or title from the toolbar so I will then call the function to fetch the data from JSON.

Here is the app_bar_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyLogin.AppBarOverlay">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.MyLogin.PopupOverlay" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:backgroundTint="#DA4336"
        app:tint="@color/white"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_edit_white_24dp" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Here is what I want to get the "Inbox" text from the toolbar:

[image]

I have tried on google to find the answer but I couldn't find it anywhere.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `(toolbar_text == "Inbox")` are you sure this is how you compare strings in java ?

Comment: Yes I did but it didnt work. I have also tried toolbar_text.equal("Inbox") but the toolbar_text show as null. Do you know how I can get the text/title from the toolbar?

Comment: @a_local_nobody There is only one Toolbar I use in the xml which is toolbar. I have updated in my post for app_bar_main.xml. Please check.

Comment: @a_local_nobody This is what I found `<fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_inbox"
        android:name="com.loginpage.ui.inbox.InboxFragment"
        android:label="Inbox2"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_inbox" />` so how I can get the text from the fragment?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by `getTitle()` if you are in an activity

```
if (getTitle().equals("Inbox")) {
   //do something        
}
```

And prepend that with `requireActivity()` if you are in a fragment

```
if (requireActivity().getTitle().equals("Inbox")) {
   //do something        
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this, I have tried getTtitle() but it wont get pass and I cant use requireActivity as I dont have it. Any idea?

Comment: @chrisoojer Can you please provide the relevant code of activity and the style file